# Find all functions satisfying certain requirements

Tags: functions, integers, gcd-and-lcm

The requirements are:

- $f(x, y) = f(y, x)$
- $f(x, x) = x$
- $f(x, y) = f(x, x + y)$
- f: $\mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$

I think $\gcd(x, y)$ works, but haven't found any other solutions nor have I been able to prove gcd is the sole function that works.

Comment: Does $\mathbb{N}$ contain $0$ here or not? If not, then $\gcd$ is the only possible function. For a proof, try strong induction on $x+y$.

Comment: It seems to me multiples of $\gcd$ might also work.

Comment: @RobertLewis The condition $f(x,x)=x$ fails in that case.

Comment: @mfl:  you mean as in: if $f(x, y) = a \gcd(x, y), a \ne 1$, then $f(x, x) = a \gcd(x, x) = a x \ne x = f(x, x)$?  Right!

Comment: @RobertLewis Yes. I mean that.